# user.firstname Not available in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i created a webapplication with asp.net core 5 and when i created that, i added individual for authentication then add blow codes but when i want to access FirstName with (user.FirstName) in index.cshtml.cs i can't do that.
how can i this work?

**Areas.Identity.Data.AuthUser.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the AuthUser class
    public class AuthUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.*Index.cshtml.cs***:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account;
using RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public IndexModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [Display(Name = "ایمیل")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }


        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "نام")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Phone]
            [Display(Name = "شماره موبایل")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        }

        private async Task LoadAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

            Username = userName;

            Input = new InputModel
            {
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
            };
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"کاربری یافت نشد '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"کاربری یافت نشد '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await LoadAsync(user);
                return Page();
            }

            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
            {
                var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
                if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    StatusMessage = "خطای غیرمنتظره هنگام تلاش برای تنظیم شماره تلفن.";
                    return RedirectToPage();
                }
            }

            // i added these
            if (Input.FirstName != user.FirstName)
            {
                user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
            }

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            //888888888888888888

            await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
            StatusMessage = "پروفایل شما بروز رسانی شد";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.*Index.cshtml***:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "پروفایل";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
}

<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
<partial name="_StatusMessage" model="Model.StatusMessage" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form id="profile-form" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" disabled />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" disabled />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**RealeStateSystem.Data.*ApplicationDbContext.cs***:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RealEstateSystem.Models;
using RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace RealEstateSystem.Data
{
    // added <AuthUser, IdentityRole, string> in below
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AuthUser, IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AuthUser> AuthUsers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PropertyDetails> PropertyDetails { get; set; }

        // Added
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
        // **************************
    }
}
```

**RealeStateSystem.Models.*PropertyDetails.cs***:

```
namespace RealEstateSystem.Models
{
    public class PropertyDetails
    {
        public PropertyDetails()
        {

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "عنوان")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(4000)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "توضیحات")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //public byte[] Images { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تصاویر")]
        public string Images { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "قیمت")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "موقعیت")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "پارکینگ")]
        public bool Parking { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "انباری")]
        public bool Warehouse { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "آسانسور")]
        public bool Elevator { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "طبقه")]
        public string Floor { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "موارد را بدرستی وارد نمایید")]
        [Display(Name = "سال ساخت")]
        public DateTime? YearofConstruction { get; set; }

    }
```

**RealeStateSystem.*startup.cs***:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using RealEstateSystem.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RealEstateSystem
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(
            //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            //services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=PropertyDetails}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.*IdentityHostingStartup***:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.Data;
using RealEstateSystem.Data;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace RealEstateSystem.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<AuthUser>(options => 
                         options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

** Folder structure **

[image]

[image]

inside **Index.cshtml** & **Index.cshtml.cs** (*user.FirstName*) not avalible.

thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inside Index.cshtml & Index.cshtml.cs (user.FirstName) not avalible.

That is because you dependency injection the service with `IdentityUser`. Change the following code:

```
public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
}
```

To:

```
public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<AuthUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<AuthUser> _signInManager;

    public IndexModel(
        UserManager<AuthUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<AuthUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
}
```

#### and

```
private async Task LoadAsync(IdentityUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Username = userName;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
    };
}
```

#### to

```
private async Task LoadAsync(AuthUser user)
{
    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Username = userName;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
    };
}
```